# If Tags is depreciated, how should the template be identified when sending a notification?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

When constructing a template, Visual Studio claims that the `Tags` property is deprecated. If this is the case, then how else does one identify a template when sending a notification?

```
new InstallationTemplate { Tags = "Hello!" });
```

Comment: Isn't the Tags property an IList<string>? Also, I'm not getting a deprecated notice when setting an IList<string> for Tags in Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs version 2.16.0.0. What are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0 Preview 1 for dontnet core.

Comment: @RobReagan Can you answer this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122012/how-to-update-an-installation-if-installation-id-is-unknown?

Comment: Yep! I put in my two cents on your other question.