# How to update an installation if installation id is unknown?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

For some reason, one cannot download all installations. So, how does one go about updating a template for all installations if one doesn't know all the installation ids?

Surely someone thought of this...?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options when using NotificationHubs: register a device directly with the NotificationHub, or register a device through your web backend.

If you're registering directly with the NotificationHub from a device, you're going to have a bad time when you need to update a template for all installations. To my knowledge, you're SOL in this case.

If you're registering with the NotificationHub from your backend, you have options. You'll need to keep a list of every installation in a separate data store. For example, on my last project, I kept a PushNotificationRegistrations database table that contained the PNS type (gcm, apns), the registrationId (the unique device registration from the respective PNS), the userId (so I could swap out tags as needed later), and a generated installationId.

If you've got this information for each registration, you can retrieve the relevant records from your data store, then re-register each with the NotificationHub in one big giant decadent for-loop. Installations are idempotent, so this will overwrite old templates. I *think* that you need to ensure that your InstallationId and registration Id are the same when you re-register.

I remember seeing something in the REST docs about using a HTTP PATCH endpoint to just target portions of an installation, but I haven't experimented with them.

Comment: The results of `FetchRegistrations` appears to include installations. It's added the installation id as a tag in the following format... `$InstallationId:{id...}`. I'm not surprised actually. I'm not sure if it's safe depending on this implementation detail though.

Comment: Regardless, if I set installation ids to be user id + device type, then I could run through every user and fish out all installations by trial and error.

Comment: Oh, doesn't list them everytime. I think I will stick to registrations.